# FBML applications with new Facebook graph / OAuth API?

Tags: oauth, facebook, fbml

The new Facebook graph / [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) seems to be only for iFrame / connect applications? Is it possible to use the OAuth system for FBML applications?

Comment: Given the richness of the Facebook Javascript SDK, I think the Facebook Team is recommending any new development be done using the iFrame and the Javascript SDK.  You may want to consider doing an iFrame app as opposed to FBML if it's "new".

Answer (score 0):

FBML will probably vanish in 2011. Please check facebook developer roadmap and concentrate on developing iframe based applications (and later on also iframe based tabs)